# Inner Join on Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm having difficulties getting an inner join statement to work that is combining a common data element on 4 different tables.

Table 1: TWSchwabPlanSponsor
Table 2: TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA
Table 3: TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor
Table 4: TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent

The common field on all 4 tables is `CUSIP`. What I'm trying to do is add the purchases from all 4 tables for a specific `CUSIP` (543917108). This `CUSIP` is present on all 4 tables. The results should display the `Fund Name` and the total amount of purchases.

The attached statement will run but the results do not match what I get when manually adding the raw data.

```
SELECT        
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.[Fund Name], 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.[Purchases ($)]
     + MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.Purchases 
     + MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor.Purchases
     + MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.Purchases AS 'Purchases'

FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent 
INNER JOIN MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA 
    ON MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.CUSIP =
       MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP 
INNER JOIN MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor 
    ON MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP = 
       MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor.CUSIP 
INNER JOIN MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor 
    ON MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP =
       MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.CUSIP

WHERE (MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP = '543917108')

GROUP BY 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP, 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.[Fund Name], 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.[Purchases ($)], 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.Purchases, 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor.Purchases, 
    MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.Purchases
```

Comment: You need to provide us with sample data of what you are getting and what you want to get. How would we know what you want to get????

Comment: Why the group by? Sample input/output/expected would help here.

Comment: Database diagram, sample input, output will be better for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use following query statement , as i not tested it , if there any error let me know.
if any table return multiple rows , then use aggrigate (Sum) query .

```
SELECT        
MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.[Fund Name], 
MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.[Purchases ($)]
 +
ISNULL((Select MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.Purchases FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA WHERE MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.CUSIP =
   MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP ) ,0 )

 +
 ISNULL( (SELECT MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor.Purchases FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor WHERE MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP = 
   MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor.CUSIP ) ,0 )

 + 
 ISNULL( (SELECT MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.Purchases FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor WHERE MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP =
   MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.CUSIP) ,0)

 AS 'Purchases'
```

FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent

WHERE (MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP = '543917108')

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response I appreciate it. I am supposed to use the last part that you have there correct? I added that in at the bottom. I receive the following error that will be shown in another comment.                                            FROM MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent

WHERE (MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP = '543917108')

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabPlanSponsor.Fund Name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.Purchases ($)" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "MARSLite.dbo.TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent.CUSIP" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP" could not be bound.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The multi-part identifier "MARSLite.dbo.TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA.CUSIP" could not be bound.

Comment: Here is sample data from each of the 4 tables: Fidelity Detail by Correspondent: Fund Name CUSIP Purchases ($)
ABC INTERNATIONAL 543917108 3696
ABC INTERNATIONAL 543917108 716

Comment: Plan Sponsor: Fund Name CUSIP Purchases
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $80
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $0

Comment: Investment Advisor: Fund Name CUSIP Purchases
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $ 100,000
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $ 64,518

Comment: Broker Dealer TPA: Fund Name CUSIP Purchases
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $ 100
ABC International Fund Investor Class 543917108 $ 50

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, I got this to work using the below code.

SELECT [CUSIP], [Fund Name], Sum(Purchases) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Ending Asset Balance]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWSchwabBrokerDealerTPA]

Group By [Fund Name], [CUSIP]

UNION 
  SELECT [CUSIP], [Fund Name], Sum(Purchases) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Ending Asset Balance]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWSchwabInvestmentAdvisor]

Group By [Fund Name],[CUSIP]

UNION 
  SELECT [CUSIP],[Fund Name], Sum(Purchases) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Ending Balance]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWSchwabPlanSponsor]

Group By [Fund Name], [CUSIP]

```
UNION
```

SELECT [CUSIP], [Fund Name], Sum([Purchases ($)]) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Assets ($)]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions ($)]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWFidelityDetailByCorrespondent]

Group By [Fund Name], [CUSIP]

UNION 
  SELECT [CUSIP], [Fund Name], Sum([Purchases ($)]) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Assets ($)]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions ($)]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWFidelityDetailByCusip]

Group By [Fund Name], [CUSIP]

```
UNION
```

SELECT [CUSIP], [Fund Name], Sum([Purchases ($)]) As 'Purchases', Sum ([Assets ($)]) As 'Assets', Sum ([Redemptions ($)]) As 'Redemptions'
  FROM [MARSLite].[dbo].[TWFidelityDetailByIWSClient]

Group By [Fund Name], [CUSIP]